# I need whole type writing text to stay on the page for a while before disappearing for the second loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

**1**. I need whole type writing text to stay on the display once it is completely written before the second loop. Please apply the solution on my code.

**2**. Secondly, in my text string when I use "b" or "strong" tags for making specific text bold, '<' sign shows in display for some milliseconds during typing, same thing happens with all other tags. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Below is my code.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  task(i);
}

function task(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Add tasks to do 
    var typeString = ['• I m Mr.Frits.\n• and   I <b>love </b> Pakistan...:)'];
    var i = 0;
    var count = 0
    var selectedText = '';
    var text = '';
    
    (function type() {
      if (count == typeString.length) {
        count = 0;
      }

      selectedText = typeString[count];
      text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
      document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(6);
      document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
      document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
      document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "normal";

      if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
        count++;
        i = 0;
      }

      /* SOLUTION : wait two seconds when new line */
      if (typeString[0][i - 1] == '\n') {
        setTimeout(type, 1000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(type, 100);
      }
    }());
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<pre id="typing"></pre>
```

Comment: @Daniel_knights what do you suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As count is set to `1` once the length of the end of the string is reached, you can add conditional and increase the timeout if this is met:

```
/* SOLUTION : wait two seconds when new line */
if (typeString[0][i - 1] == '\n') {
    setTimeout(type, 1000);
} else if (count === 1) {
    setTimeout(type, 3000);
} else {
    setTimeout(type, 100);
}
```

With the `<br />`'s, the browser doesn't register it as valid HTML until the tag is completed. So, for a second, all that's rendered is `<` before the rest of the tag completes and it understands what that tag is.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  task(i);
}

function task(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Add tasks to do 
    var typeString = ['• I m Mr.Frits.\n• and   I love  Pakistan...:)'];
    var i = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var selectedText = '';
    var text = '';
    var typing = document.getElementById('typing');

    (function type() {
      if (count == typeString.length) {
        count = 0;
      };

      selectedText = typeString[count];
      text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
      typing.innerHTML = text.fontsize(6);
      typing.style.fontFamily = "monospace";
      typing.style.color = "black";
      typing.style.fontWeight = "normal";

      if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
        count++;
        i = 0;
      }

      /* SOLUTION : wait two seconds when new line */
      if (typeString[0][i - 1] == '\n') {
        setTimeout(type, 1000);
      } else if (count === 1) {
        setTimeout(type, 3000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(type, 100);
      }
    }());
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<pre id="typing"></pre>
```

Comment: @Danial_knights 50% problem solved as the text stayed. But the loop is also stopped. Can we set time for the text to stay and the second loop starts after few seconds.

Comment: Also what is the alternate solution to make specific characters bold? Thanks

Comment: Updated my snippet. To make specific characters bold, you'd have to wrap them in a span with `font-weight: bold` before inserting it.